# Is my interpretation correct about n3797 8.5.3/5?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, language-lawyer, c++14

Paragraph 8.5.3/5 in [n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf):

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type
>   “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
>   - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,” or
>   - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, **and can be converted to an lvalue of type
>       “cv3 T3,”** where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3” (this
>       conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion
>       functions (13.3.1.6) and choosing the best one through overload
>       resolution (13.3)),
>
> ...

English is not my native language, but the phrase in bold (my emphasis) seems to me to give the idea that `T1` can be converted to an lvalue of type *cv3 T3*, which I believe is not correct. According to my understanding, `T2` is the type who has to be convertible to *cv3 T3*, as the example:

```
struct B : A { operator int&(); } b;    
int& ir = B();
```

shows.

Comment: `N3485` is the last *C++11* draft, what you are referencing would be `C++1y`, see [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/4653479#4653479)

Comment: Since you quote `N3797` this applies to *C++1y* as well. The wording is nearly identical in `N3485`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not reading it correctly, this is how you should be reading it:

> the initializer expression ... has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type) ... and can be
>   converted to an lvalue of type “cv3 T3,”

where *the initializer expression* refers back to:

> [...]is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows

Answer (score 1):

**No**, your interpretation is wrong.

- `T1 =` the reference that is initialized
- `T2 =` the class type
- `T3 =` the lvalue that `T2` can be converted to

The quoted snippet is stating that `T2` (ie. the class type) can be converted to an lvalue of type `T3` where `T1` is reference-compatible with `T3`, but that `T1` is *not* reference-related to `T2`.

Comment: Seems to me that both answers are correct but could be better expressed.

Comment: @david.pfx: Then post a better answer?

Comment: @david.pfx: That's not how Stack Overflow works. Accepting is for the asker. Answers are for the community. If you have something useful to say, it'd be a welcome addition.